# config route to eliminate index.php in the url

Tags: php, .htaccess

My input url needs index.php to work

for example
http://example.com/index.php/classname/function

How can I change it into http://example.com/classname/function

[**SOLUTION**]
Delete index.php in my config['uri']="index.php";
Add a .htaccess as Brendan mentioned below into the same folder where "system" is located
IT WORKS THEN! :-D

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

For more information on mod_rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess (check if mod_rewrite enabled)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and something like this in your index.php

```
$request = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/\/\\ \t\n\r\0\x0B");
$qPos = strpos($request, '?');
$route = explode('/', substr($request, 0, $qPos===false ? 1024 : $qPos));
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.slimframework.com/ this might interest you, in addition to the .htaccess. :)

Slim provides pretty nice routing functionality.